# Want to take backup of code in PHP where files which are to be taken as backup is read from another specified (patch)folder.?

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii, cron, backup

I need to take backup of code for my Project, but the condition is :-

I generate a Patch folder through SVN, which has files structured in the same way as it is in the main Project folder (the patch has lesser files than the main project). I want to write a code which reads the main project  and picks only those files which are present in the patch and saves it in a new backup folder.

The code which i wrote is :-

```
    /*Patch Folder */
     $frmFoldr = 'patch_test/';
     $basepath = '/var/www/html/TestingBackupCron/';


    /*The Folder where files are to be backed up it would use basepath and toFoldr folder name. */
    $toFoldr = 'axisdirectcheck/';

    /* Read/Copy File from this folder. */
    $prodMainFolder = '';
    $prodBasePath = '/var/www/html/TestingBackupCron/sijucheckfiles/';


    $dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($basepath . $frmFoldr);
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
        $readDir = strstr($file->getPathname(), $frmFoldr);
        $tofileminpath = str_replace($frmFoldr, "", $readDir);

        $fromExPath = $prodBasePath . $tofileminpath;
        $toExPath = $basepath . $toFoldr . $tofileminpath;

        if (strpos($fromExPath, '.php') || strpos($fromExPath, '.js') || strpos($fromExPath, '.css')) {
            if (file_exists($fromExPath)) {
                copy($fromExPath, $toExPath);
                print_r('Files copied to ' . $toExPath . ".\n");
            }else{
                print_r($fromExPath." ::: Read path not found.\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code gives me the error "failed to open stream: No such file or directory". I think copy doesn't create folders. Please help guys.

Comment: Making a partial backup when you have everything in source control seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: We have a 600+ MB of main project files. I felt taking all of it as backup is unnecessary.

Comment: My point was actually that you don't need a separate / non-version-control backup at all when you use version control :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Below code would create folders first and then on the next loop it would write the copied files onto those folders.

```
public function run($args) {
    /*Patch Folder */
    $frmFoldr = 'patch_test/';
    $basepath = '/var/www/html/TestingBackupCron/';

    /*The Folder where files are to be backed up it would use basepath and toFoldr folder name. */
    $toFoldr = 'axisdirectcheck/';

    /* Read/Copy File from this folder. */
    $prodMainFolder = '';
    $prodBasePath = '/var/www/html/TestingBackupCron/sijucheckfiles/';


    if (file_exists($basepath . $frmFoldr)) {
        $dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($basepath . $frmFoldr);
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    } else{
        print_r("Read Directory '$basepath$frmFoldr' not Found. Please check the read directory filename.\n");
        exit;
    }
    $fromDir = array();

    $sendToArray = array();

    /* this foreach would create folders inside the path ($toFoldr) specified */
    foreach ($iterator as $file) {
        $readDir = strstr($file->getPathname(), $frmFoldr);
        $tofileminpath = str_replace($frmFoldr, "", $readDir);

        $fromExPath = $basepath . $readDir;
        $toExPath = $basepath . $toFoldr . $tofileminpath;
        $sendToArray[] = $tofileminpath;

        if (strpos($file, '/.')) {
            if (!file_exists($toExPath)) {
                $oldmask = umask(0);
                mkdir("$toExPath", 0777, true);
                umask($oldmask);
            }
        }
    }

    /* this foreach would copy files from PROD/UAT and paste inside the path($toExPath) specified */
    foreach ($sendToArray as $fPath) {
        $fromExPath = $prodBasePath . $fPath;
        $toExPath = $basepath . $toFoldr . $fPath;

        if (strpos($fromExPath, '.php') || strpos($fromExPath, '.js') || strpos($fromExPath, '.css')) {
            if (file_exists($fromExPath)) {
                copy($fromExPath, $toExPath);
                print_r('Files copied to ' . $toExPath . ".\n");
            }else{
                print_r($fromExPath." ::: Read path not found.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks..